# Highchart data series filled with different colors

Tags: javascript, colors, highcharts

I need to figure out how to color the same data series points with different colors in Highcharts. For example, let's say I have a data series for several days and I would like to have a line graph. In this line specific days should be distinguish (maybe colored by some color).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#series

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the `fillColor` property:

```
{
    name: 'xyz',
    x: 123,
    y: 456,
    fillColor: '#00FF00'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked! It would be great to have the connectors also filled with special color. Is it possible?

Comment: The "connectors" are actually the series color. See this example, with the series set as green, and specific points set to various colors:  http://jsfiddle.net/xqWp5/1/

Answer (score 11):

In your data, you can specify the color of the specific points:

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

For line charts, use "fill color", as explained in the answer below.

For an example in jsFiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/xqWp5/1/

Comment: Here's a link to the API documentation describing this:  http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series--data

Comment: I think this would work for tpye: 'column' , but I need it for line chart. For ex.

$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        
        series: [{
            data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]      
        }]
    });
});
but it doesn't changes the point's color itself, it sets  the  tooltip's color.

Comment: Would you please just bring a simple example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just use plotOptions.area.zones :

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones

see the example :

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        zoneAxis: "x",
        zones: [{
            value: 0,
            className: 'zone-0'
        }, {
            value: 10,
            className: 'zone-1'
        }, {
            className: 'zone-2'
        }],
        threshold: -10
    }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/css/color-zones/

With the `zoneAxis: "x"` you can specify which axis you use to discriminate your differents colors.

Answer (score 0):

You you would like to have colored line partially, you need to have as much series as colors. In other words, each color should be separate series with defined color.